# fit youtube embed playlist on website

Tags: javascript, css, html, youtube, playlist

I am trying to embed a youtube playlist within a div on a website. the videos have various sizes. Some of the videos contains black borders at the sides and some at the top and buttom. So how do I set the style so the videos have a consistent size without black borders. Can you point me to the right reference.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For each video that you would like to embed, you should use classes to create a consistent look. In the following example, a `video-box` class was created which removes any border, sets the height to 100px, and set the width to 200px. Any time you would like to have this consistent look, add `class="video-box"` to the `iframe`.

I have also included two classes which include borders on opposite side with colors.

> Example

```css
.video-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
}
.border-top-bottom {
  border-top: 5px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
}
.border-left-right {
  border-left: 5px solid yellow;
  border-right: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <iframe class="video-box border-top-bottom" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eU66as4Bbds" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe class="video-box" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eU66as4Bbds" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe class="video-box border-left-right" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eU66as4Bbds" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for that but I thought there would be a more effecient way as there will be a lot of swop and changing of videos.